# Edit js for some libraries like Slick in Drupal

Tags: javascript, drupal, drupal-modules

I am new to Drupal and I want to change slick library in js file named slick.js, but I don't know after change how can I apply these changes to my site. after I change slick.js and flush all caches in my site, there is nothing to change in my site.

I change some lines from default option like change autoplay speed for slick and expect to change after saving and flush caches.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to change the core file of slick library, you can always change the settings from initialization e.g.

```
$('.class-name').slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 500,
  fade: true,
  autoplay: true,
  cssEase: 'linear'
});
```

For further details please refer to this link .
https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/